# Large gap between/after images in thumbnail scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the use of the jQuery "Any List Scroller" I've added it to my site, however there seems to always be a large gap between some of the images, first 4 on this example link shows up fine but scroll (press the grey btn/image at the bottom right of the thumbnails) and you'll see the gap start to appear.

Can't see any immediate reason why it's got that. Any ideas? The containers arn't any bigger than they should be adding to any type of margin I can see.

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1bJMREc

```
<div class="als-container product-thumb-carousel" id="demo2">
                  <span class="als-prev"><img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="prev" title="previous" style="z-index: 99999; position: absolute; left: 70px; top: 40px;" /></span>
                  <div class="als-viewport">
                  <ul class="als-wrapper">
                    <?php $i=0;
                    $rsThumb->data_seek(0);
                     if ($row_rsThumb){ while ($row_rsThumb = $rsThumb->get_row_assoc()){
                     $ww = $dimensions[$i][0];
                     $hh = $dimensions[$i][1];
                     if ($ww > $hh){
                        $dimm = 'width='.(70);
                    } else {
                        $dimm = 'height='.(70);
                    }
                     $i++;                   
                     ?>
                        <div class="product-select">
                            <a class="thumb_button" id="thumb_<?php echo $i; ?>" href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST.'upload/full/'.$row_rsThumb['fileId'].'_'.$row_rsThumb['fileName']; ?>"><li class="als-item"><img id="img_<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php echo $dimm;?> src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST.'upload/340w/'.$row_rsThumb['fileId'].'_'.$row_rsThumb['fileName']; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlentities(truncate($page->row['pageTitle'])); ?>" /></li></a>
                        </div>
                    <?php } 
                    } ?>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#demo2").als({
                    visible_items: 4,
                    scrolling_items: 2,
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    circular: "yes",
                    autoscroll: "no"
                });
            </script>
```

CSS

```
/*************************************
 * generic styling for ALS elements
 ************************************/

.als-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

.als-viewport {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.als-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

.als-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.als-prev, .als-next {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    clear: both;
}

/*************************************
 * specific styling for #demo2
 ************************************/

#demo2 {
    /* margin: 40px auto; */
}

#demo2 .als-item {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 4px 0px;
    min-height: 120px;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#demo2 .als-item img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#demo2 .als-prev, #demo2 .als-next {
    top: 40px;
}

#demo2 .als-prev {
    left: 200px;
}

#demo2 .als-next {
    right: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the generated source code, you will want to make the UL direct child elements valid list item elements, instead of what you have currently which is:

[image]

```
ul > div > a > li
```

when it should in fact be:

```
ul > li > a > span
```

I have swapped out the div for a span, as you shouldn't really be inserting block level elements (li) within an inline element (a). The order of nesting has been changed to ensure everything within your anchor is clickable, too.

When you have made these changes, lets see what it comes back with. =)

Comment: `<li>` isn't an inline element, but `<a>` is. Otherwise good point with the HTML structure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this typo out. It has now been corrected. =)

Comment: You mean the block elements `<li>` not to insert into `<a>` ?

Comment: I mean the nesting of the generated HTML should be: ul > li > a > span

Comment: Yes, yes. But you typed that the `<div>`s are illegally nested in the `<a>`s. But the `<div>`s are not nested inside th `<a>`s. It's the `<li>`s that are nested inside the `<a>`s

Comment: What can I say - it's been a long ol' day. Thanks. =)

Comment: In all honesty I tried and successfully changed it to use a different carousel in the end, got half way through implementing your changes. New owl.carousel works fine, but I appreciate the help and code you provided. Awarded.

Answer (score 1):

Because your top container div has an id of "demo2",

```
<div class="als-container product-thumb-carousel" id="demo2">
```

all of the elements inside the div are being styled with the "#demo2" section of your css file instead of the generic styling section.

For instance, als-item now gets width of 100px (which is too wide) from the '#demo2 als-item{' entry.

There are 4 thumbnails and the width is only 300px for four.  The thumbnails are set at 72px but the 'li' element is 100px.

Math is off somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes to your stylesheet.

```
div#content #details-2 #product .product-select {
    height: 72px;
    width: 72px;
} 

#demo2 .als-item {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 72px;
    min-width: 72px;
    padding: 0;
}
```